# Can I do “complex” mutual recursion in Coq without let-binding?

Tags: recursion, coq, termination, mutual-recursion

Consider the following pair of mutually recursive Coq data types, which represent a `Forest` of nonempty `Tree`s.  Each `Branch` of a `Tree` holds an extra boolean flag, which we can extract with `isOK`.

```
Inductive Forest a : Type
  := Empty    : Forest a
  |  WithTree : Tree a -> Forest a -> Forest a
with Tree a : Type
  := Branch : bool -> a -> Forest a -> Tree a.

Arguments Empty    {_}.
Arguments WithTree {_} _ _.
Arguments Branch   {_} _ _ _.

Definition isOK {a} (t : Tree a) : bool :=
  match t with
  | Branch ok _ _ => ok
  end.
```

Now, if we ignore this boolean flag, we can write a pair of mapping functions to apply a function to every value in a `Forest` or a `Tree`, and this works fine:

```
Fixpoint mapForest_always {a} (f : a -> a) (ts0 : Forest a) {struct ts0} : Forest a :=
  match ts0 with
  | Empty         => Empty
  | WithTree t ts => WithTree (mapTree_always f t) (mapForest_always f ts)
  end
with mapTree_always {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) {struct t} : Tree a :=
  match t with
  | Branch ok x ts => Branch ok (f x) (mapForest_always f ts)
  end.
```

However, suppose the boolean represents some validity check, which would be more complicated in real code.  So we check the boolean first, and only actually recurse  if necessary.  This means we have *three* mutually recursive functions, but one of them is just handing the work along.  Unfortunately, this doesn’t work:

```
Fail Fixpoint mapForest_bad {a} (f : a -> a) (ts0 : Forest a) {struct ts0} : Forest a :=
  match ts0 with
  | Empty         => Empty
  | WithTree t ts => WithTree (mapTree_bad f t) (mapForest_bad f ts)
  end
with mapTree_bad {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) {struct t} : Tree a :=
  if isOK t
  then mapOKTree_bad f t
  else t
with mapOKTree_bad {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) {struct t} : Tree a :=
  match t with
  | Branch ok x ts => Branch ok (f x) (mapForest_bad f ts)
  end.
```

The problem is that `mapTree_bad` calls into `mapOKTree_bad` on an argument that isn’t actually smaller.

Except… all `mapOKTree_bad` is doing is an extra step after some preprocessing.  This *will* always terminate, but Coq can’t see that.  To persuade the termination checker, we can instead define `mapOKTree_good`, which is the same but is a local `let`-binding; then, the termination checker will see through the `let`-binding and allow us to define `mapForest_good` and `mapTree_good`.  If we want to get `mapOKTree_good`, we can just use a plain old definition after we’ve defined the mutually recursive functions, which just has the same body as the `let`-binding:

```
Fixpoint mapForest_good {a} (f : a -> a) (ts0 : Forest a) {struct ts0} : Forest a :=
  match ts0 with
  | Empty         => Empty
  | WithTree t ts => WithTree (mapTree_good f t) (mapForest_good f ts)
  end
with mapTree_good {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) {struct t} : Tree a :=
  let mapOKTree_good {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) : Tree a :=
        match t with
        | Branch ok x ts => Branch ok (f x) (mapForest_good f ts)
        end in
  if isOK t
  then mapOKTree_good f t
  else t.

Definition mapOKTree_good {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) : Tree a :=
  match t with
  | Branch ok x ts => Branch ok (f x) (mapForest_good f ts)
  end.
```

This works, but it’s not pretty.  Is there any way to convince Coq’s termination checker to accept the `_bad` variants, or is the `_good` trick the best I’ve got?  A command that does work for me, such as `Program Fixpoint` or `Function`, is a totally reasonable solution as well.

Comment: Is `mapTree_good` supposed to invoke `mapForest_good` instead of `mapForest_always`? As you've written it, the definition of `mapOKTree_good` stands completely on its own.

Comment: Thanks, Jennifer – fixed!

Comment: `mapOKTree_good` skips only the first check (because then `mapForest_good` calls `mapTree_good`). Is this intended semantics?

Comment: @AntonTrunov: On the one hand, yes (the semantics is to short-circuits when `isOK t` is `false`); on the other hand, it doesn’t really matter, as the point is about the recursion issues :-)

Comment: I'm asking because if it wasn't the intended semantics, there would be yet another generalization, viz. over `isOK`, and then we would have `Definition mapOKTree_good {a} (f : a -> a) : Tree a -> Tree a :=
  mapTree_good f (fun _ => true).` And, yes, I think when programming in total languages we should always start with the meaning of the program at *hand* ;) Take the notorious `intercalate` function for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very partial answer: we can refactor the two definitions of `mapOKTree_good` with an intermediate definition parameterized by `mapForest_good` just before it is defined.

```
Definition mapOKTree_good_ {a} mapForest_good
           (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) : Tree a :=
  match t with
  | Branch ok x ts => Branch ok (f x) (mapForest_good f ts)
  end.

Fixpoint mapForest_good {a} (f : a -> a) (ts0 : Forest a) {struct ts0} : Forest a :=
  match ts0 with
  | Empty         => Empty
  | WithTree t ts => WithTree (mapTree_good f t) (mapForest_good f ts)
  end
with mapTree_good {a} (f : a -> a) (t : Tree a) {struct t} : Tree a :=
  if isOK t
  then mapOKTree_good_ mapForest_good f t
  else t.

Definition mapOKTree_good {a} := @mapOKTree_good_ a mapForest_good.
```